# In Fitnesse: command to run stating which test you would like to start and end untill the end of test suite

Tags: fitnesse

In Fitnesse Commands: `http://<host>:<port>/<suite path and test name>?responder=suite&startTest=TestTwo`. I tried to execute. It is executing the test case which is passed in the url. If we pass the suite path and remove the test name, it is executing the whole suite. Is there any way we can run all tests coming after `TestTwo`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can run an entire suite or you can run an individual test. Perhaps you can break the suite into smaller sub-suites?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **firstTest** parameters when calling the url. In your case, you can do:

`http://<host>:<port>/<suite path>?responder=suite&firstTest=TestTwo`

Note that, this only works based on alphabetical order of full path names of the test cases as mentioned in the fitnesse wiki [here](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.AdministeringFitNesse.RestfulServices)

> firstTest: if present, only tests whose full path names are lexigraphically greater (later in alphabetical order) will be run. This is of questionable use since tests are not guaranteed to be run in any particular order.

Alternatively, you can tag certain test cases with tags, and execute them using parameter `suiteFilter`. You can find the relevant documentation in the same wiki page.